# R: How to identify indices of minima of all groups in data frame

Tags: r, greatest-n-per-group

In R, say I have a data frame *times* of times with columns: athlete (character), season (integer), distance (factor, out of 400, 800, 1500, 5000, 10000) and tm (float) and want to identify the indices of rows that are the lowest value of *time* for each unique combination of the other four variables.

I can do this with the following code that sorts by grouping columns and then by tm:

```
times1 <- times # make copy of array
times1$rownum <- 1:nrow(times1) # add column of row numbers
times1 <- times1[with(times1, order(athlete, season, distance, tm)), ] # sort array
whichmins <- times1$rownum[!duplicated(subset(times1, select = -c(tm, rownum)))] # identify rows where grouping factors change
```

But I was wondering if there was a more concise way to do it using aggregate, dplyr or data tables.
I tried using dplyr's *group_by* function with *which.min* but I could not get it to work.

Thank you

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, similar approach would be to `arrange` by the columns, `filter` the distinct elements based on the logical vector from `duplicated` and `pull` the 'rownum'

```
library(dplyr)
times %>%
     mutate(rownum = row_number()) %>%
     arrange(athlete, season, distance, tm) %>%
     filter(!duplicated(select(., -c(tm, rownum))) %>%
     pull(rownum)
```

Or instead of `duplicated`, use the `distinct`

```
times %>%
   mutate(rownum = row_number()) %>%
   arrange(athlete, season, distance, tm) %>%
   distinct(across(-c(tm, rownum)), .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
   pull(rownum)
```

---

If we want to use a group by operation, then after the grouping by 'athlete', 'season', 'distance', slice the row where the 'tm' is `min`imum and `pull` the 'rownum'

```
times %>%
    mutate(rownum = row_number())
    group_by(athlete, season, distance) %>%
    slice_min(tm) %>%
    pull(rownum)
```

Or with `summarise`

```
times %>%
    mutate(rownum = row_number())
    group_by(athlete, season, distance) %>%
    summarise(rownum = rownum[which.min(tm)]) %>%
    pull(rownum)
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(times)[order(athlete, season, distance, tm), 
   .I[!duplicated(.SD[, setdiff(names(.SD), 'tm')), with = FALSE])]]
```

Or with `unique`

```
unique(setorder(setorder(setDT(times, keep.rownames = TRUE),
      athlete, season, distance, tm), by = c('athlete', 'season', 'distance'))[, rn]
```

Comment: Thank you arun. A very helpful response!